# Searching an object with a WHERE like approach?

Tags: javascript

I have this object structure which comes from a service:

```
var response ={"results": [
{"name":"peter" , "habits":"smoking" , "imgID":"something_unique"},
{"name":"paul"  , "habits":"drinking" , "imgID":"something_unique"},
{"name":"patrick" , "habits":"gambling" , "imgID":"something_unique"}
]}
```

I iterate the object and create divs which are listened to by a click event:

```
for(var prop in response) {
        if(response.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            {       
this.div.insert(new Element('div', {'className': '' })
.insert('<img id="'+imgID+'" src="/img.jpg" width=70 height=70 /> ')   
                    );
```

In my callback, I can access the id from the object spawned event:

```
function callback (event) { console.log(event.id) ; var compare_ID=event.id }
```

However, in my callback, I need to get the array var name for that one particular object that was clicked. So in concept, I am looking to do:

In callback, iterate `response` object then select the `results[i]` where it's `imgID` is `== event.id return response` object for further access, not just the *string* name.

Thanks, and like always, all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [data-* attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) for storing number or key of object, or actual values. I think it would be helpful here.

E.g.:

```
<img id="something_unique" src="/img.jpg" width=70 height=70 data-result-number="1" />
```

or

```
<img id="something_unique" src="/img.jpg" width=70 height=70 data-name="peter" data-habits="smoking" />
```

Comment: How would you pass dataset to an event callback?

Comment: For example `results[event.target.getAttribute('data-result-number')]` or, like in second case, just take values directly from element `event.target.getAttribute('data-name')`. These values are attached to the element node, so you can access them by accessing to the element with `event.target`.